# codeigniter query string and segment together

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

In my project I need the query string feature and segment array feature. Because some return url is in the query string form.
I have made the following changes but it didn't work.

My `config.php` looks like

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

And my `.htaccess` file is

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$ /test/index.php [L] 
RewriteCond $1  !^(index\.php|resource|smsprinter|media|Scripts|system|public|upload|flash|css|js|pop-up|images|user_guide|scripts|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Is there any way to set the query string format in any particular page only ? Or is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Which urls are in that form? Website internal URLs or URLs from other sources (like a Paypal url, for. ex.)

Comment: @Damien Pirsy : http://dev3.tec.in/test/order/smsprinter_test?a=AC001&o=No0001&ak=Accepted

Comment: @Damien Prisy : When I enable my query string feature, my url will look like http://dev3.dec.in/test/?home/index/book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out the solution.
There is no chage in the htaccess file
But there is some change in the config file.
The config file should be
    $config['base_url'] = '';
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;